# <section> inside a <form>

Tags: html

Is it a valid thing to put a `<section>` inside a `<form>`?

Now, I know it works, so I'm not asking whether it works or not. I also know that they both are (both section and form) "box-model" elements and "may be inlined inside each other" -- according to the W3 definitions. And yet, I'm wondering if it's a legit thing to do?

Example for clarity:

```
<form action="foo.bar">
 <section>
  <input type="foo" />
 </section>
</form>
```

Comment: I just had a mindexplosion after reading this..

Comment: If you even quote the W3 definition, who should then say that it is not legit?

Comment: Those two exact phrases never appear in the HTML spec, so quoting in this way is inappropriate. What does "legit" even mean? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Tibbers Do you wanna play ? ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In HTML5 you should use the tags that are most semantically appropriate for a given task.

And indeed there is a section tag for forms – it is called `fieldset`.

So instead of using a `section` tag inside your form, you might use a `fieldset`:

```
<form action="foo.bar">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>The fiedlset heading</legend>
        <input type="foo" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Please also refer to the [„html5 Doctor Element Flowchart“ (PNG](http://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.png), [also as PDF](http://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.pdf)).

Comment: I totally agree with this advice even though it's the opposite of what's recommend by this page, '_How to structure an HTML form_' on [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form). However, that didn't sit well with me ergo, I ended up here!

Answer (score 0):

On the same page we can read:

> In addition to the  element, it's also common practice to use HTML titles (e.g. , ) and sectioning (e.g. ) to structure complex forms.

Answer (score 0):

Fieldsets with legends are absolutely the right answer for grouping things like radio buttons or checkboxes or a group of inputs that make up an address for example within your form. It is vital for making your code accessible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).